# Install Apache on Debian VPS & unmet dependencies error

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, dependencies, debian

I have a VPS and it runs on Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie). I try to install Apache, PHP, and MySQL on it. I get the below error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

When I run `apt-get -f install`, i get below error:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 39521 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.0 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have basic knowledge of Linux, so any suggestion or help. I search online and try to uninstall and remove and reinstall MySQL... but no luck.

Comment: I think your distro has MySQL 5.6+ installed. You're trying to downgrade it to 5.5.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://superuser.com. Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

from you error output i did a quick `apt-cache search` to see the version numbers of mysql-server

from what i seen you might have installed `mariadb-server-10.0` installed instead of `mysql-server`

do a `dpkg -l | grep mysql` and look at the results.  you could also try `dpkg -l | grep server` and look at that output also.

ADDED COMMENT-

did you remove the file that it's asking you to do?

if you need to have both db-servers running i would follow along with this
https://superuser.com/questions/1029228/mysql-and-mariadb-instances-on-the-same-server

if you don't need both dbs, then i would `apt-get remove mariadb-..` from your server and then `apt-get -f install` to get mysql-server installed

Comment: When I do dpkg -1 | grep mysql, I get the below output: